# How do I use SyndicationFeed?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, rss, syndication-feed

This may seem like a dumb question, but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to get access to the `SyndicationFeed` class in c#. Every single example I have seen on MSDN or otherwise assumes that it's already imported, and not a single one I have found gives any indication on where it's located.

For example, I'm trying to run the following:

```
XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(rss_url);
SyndicationFeed.Load(reader);
```

But it fails because `SyndicationFeed` doesn't exist in the current context. Does anybody out there know how I can get it in?

Comment: Resharper will figure this kind of stuff out for you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Read the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.syndication.syndicationfeed.aspx) more carefully:

> **Namespace**:  System.ServiceModel.Syndication
>   **Assembly**:  System.ServiceModel (in System.ServiceModel.dll)

Right-click your project, click Add Reference, then select System.ServiceModel.dll

Comment: I had seen that, but I was still getting errors when I tried using it. Turns out I hadn't added the reference (didn't know about that). For anybody else who may have the same issue, it was actually in the assembly `System.ServiceModel.Web` Thanks for the help!

Comment: @user1375883: It moved from `System.ServiceModel.Web` to `System.ServiceModel` in .Net 4.0.

Answer (score 0):

It [appears](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.syndication.syndicationfeed.aspx) to reside in `System.ServiceModel.Syndication`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using .NET Core, search and install the NuGet package:

```
System.ServiceModel.Syndication
```